# Reduce velocity in the Space

Tags: propulsion

As per sketch there is a ball filled with liquid launch from A point to B point at 10 meter per second.the ball is spinning clockwise and moving towards B point.but the liquid in the ball is spinning anticlockwise due to a motor mechanism.
I would like to know can we reduce the velocity of ball due to this mechanism as the liquid is spinning anticlockwise so there will be internal friction and this friction will work to reduce the velocity of ball before the ball hit the point B.

.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no.

My understanding is that you're asking about how rotational momentum can be transferred to translational momentum or vise versa.

The only way i'm aware of is by external forces (most commonly: friction), since objects naturally travel in a straight path.

So the situation which you hope only works in air, where rotating objects can take advantage of the "magnus effect" (think of Roberto Carlos free kick).

Whether you can "stir" the ball around in mid-air with a motor inside; the answer is still no, at least not indefinately. the motor might jerk the ball rotation right at the start, but eventually the rotational momentum of the system reaches equilibrium (movement of water created by motor is countered by it's own movement in the opposite direction) and the only thing the poor motor will do is to heat the ball from the inside.

Comment: Ok.but tell me if liquid is rotating anticlockwise without motor or other mechanical system then?

Comment: the result is the same. it's like how a boat stays still whether you sit still on it, or kick the edge of the boat to push the boat. neither actions actually propel the boat. in this case, you sitting still is analogous to having no motor.